# SQL Registro mais recente FROM segnda tabela by Id

Tags: sql

Eu tenho duas tabelas (`Opportunity` and `Stage`). Eu preciso pegar para cada `Opportunity` a linha da tabela `Stage` onde o `StageTypeId` for igual ao `input parameter`.

Tabela `Opportunity`

> Id, etc

Tabela `Stage`

> Id, CreatedOn, OpportunityId, StageTypeId.

Suponhamos que eu tenha as oportunidades "opportunity1" and "opportunity2" cada uma com vários `Stages` cadastrados.

Passando o `StageTypeId` eu preciso pegar as `Opportunities` que tenham esse `Id` como o mais recente na tabela `Stage`.

Estou tentando a *query* abaixo mas está replicando o `Stage` que existe para uma `Opportunity` para todas as outras `Opportunities`.

Parece que está ignorando essa linha: `AND {Stage}.[OpportunityId] = ID`

```
SELECT {Opportunity}.[Id] ID,
       {Opportunity}.[Name],
       {Opportunity}.[PotentialAmount],
       {Contact}.[FirstName], 
       {Contact}.[LastName],
       (SELECT * FROM 
            (
                SELECT {Stage}.[StageTypeId]
                  FROM {Stage}         
                 WHERE {Stage}.[StageTypeId] = @StageTypeId  
                   AND {Stage}.[OpportunityId] = ID       
                 ORDER BY {Stage}.[CreatedOn] DESC
            ) 
        WHERE ROWNUM = 1) AS StageTypeId     
 FROM {Opportunity}
 LEFT JOIN {Contact} 
   ON {Opportunity}.[ContactId] = {Contact}.[Id]
```

Obrigado.

Comment: um `max` talvez ajude aqui, mas sinceramente está difícil imaginar as tabelas,  seria mais prático postar a estrutura (campos relevantes) e um exemplo de dados pra fica rmais claro

Comment: @Denis, conseguiu resolver o seu problema?

Comment: @JoãoMartins sim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apos algum tempo eu resolvi executar a primeira *query* e depois recuperar os dados da tabela `Stage` item por item em um `Loop`.

Answer (score 1):

Olá @Denis, sei que faz tempo desde a pergunta, mas acho válido deixar citado aqui:

Essa sua abordagem de fazer uma nova query a cada loop costuma trazer problemas quando estamos falando de um grande número de registros.

O que você precisava era um Join levando em consideracao apenas 1 registro da tabela auxiliar.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d471e2/2/0

```
    SELECT opportunity.id,
      opportunity.name,
      contacts.name,
      stage.stageTypeId
  FROM opportunity
  JOIN contacts ON contacts.id = opportunity.contact_id
  JOIN (SELECT stageTypeId,MAX(createdOn),opportunityId FROM stage GROUP BY opportunityId) as stage
   ON stage.opportunityId = opportunity.id 

  WHERE stage.stageTypeId=2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d471e2/2/0